# How to change address bar url without redirecting in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My web app homepage has many card elements (like Pinterest), each click to a card will create a popup window instead of going to the associated page. I want to change the address bar url so that when users refresh the homepage with the popup window, the browser will go to the associated page. And each click to the card element will also push the associated page url to the browser history. Basically, the concept comes from Pinterest.

When I use $location.path() or $location.url(), they both redirect.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something, but why wouldn't a link work?

Comment: Because I want to create a popup window each time they click card elements for better user experience. If I use links, they will redirect to the associated page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the history from the window.

```
window.history.pushState("abc", "Title", "/the_new_happy_url");
```

Comment: how are you calling this? because if you open the console here, for example, and run my code, it will change the url without redirecting.

Comment: I am calling it from the angular app. 
 I tried it on the console; it will redirect if I click on the page.

Comment: well.. the only way I know how to change the address bar without redirecting is this way. the other guy posted a link with target blank. maybe that's what you want and I just misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. The answer actually does work. The problem is that Chrome(or maybe other browsers) internally check if the url in the address bar matches the actual page and if it doesn't they automatically direct the window to the new address...

Answer (score -2):

You don't need JavaScript.  You can open links in a new window using the `target` attribute, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click here!</a>
```